# How to find this limit $\lim_{x\to\infty} (1+\frac{1}{x})^{3x}$

Tags: limits

How do you find this limit

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} (1+\frac{1}{x})^{3x}$$

I know that $\lim_{x\to\infty} (1+\frac{1}{x})^{x}=e$, so can $$\lim_{x\to\infty} (1+\frac{1}{x})^{3x}=e^3$$

Comment: Then… what's the question?

Comment: Is my answer correct? If yes then why

Comment: @JamesWarthington Yes, because the first limit you used to get $e$ converges.

Comment: Yes. The rules of arithmetic operations on limits.

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to\infty} (1+\frac{1}{x})^{3x}=\lim_{x\to\infty} \left((1+\frac{1}{x})^{x}\right)^3=e^3$$

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you!

Comment: @JamesWarthington, you should use the #tag proof verification.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need of any extended proofs, we know that, and this is a well-known result;

$$e^n=\lim_{x\to\infty} (1+\frac{1}{x})^{nx}$$

And hence

$$e^3=\lim_{x\to\infty} (1+\frac{1}{x})^{3x}$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your proof will work here. Furthermore $\text{lim}_{x\rightarrow \infty}(1+\frac{1}{x})^{3x}=(\text{lim}_{x\rightarrow \infty}(1+\frac{1}{x})^x)(\text{lim}_{x\rightarrow \infty}(1+\frac{1}{x})^x)(\text{lim}_{x\rightarrow \infty}(1+\frac{1}{x})^x)=e^{3}$. Using the result $\text{lim}_{x\rightarrow a}fg=(\text{lim}_{x \rightarrow a}f)(\text{lim}_{x \rightarrow a}g)$, provided all the limits exists finitely.

Answer (score 0):

The main question here is whether $x \mapsto x^n$ commutes with limits. Indeed, this is pretty much the definition of continuity. So the question is whether $x \mapsto x^n$ is continuous. The answer is "yes" because:

- The identity $x \mapsto x$ is easily shown to be continuous
- The product of two continuous functions is continuous

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this:

First: lim {f(x)g(x)} = lim {f(x)} lim{g(x)}

So you could separate that function raised to power $3x$ to product of $3$ functions raised to power of $x$

Second: Limits that reduce to $1^∞$ on keeping the value that $x$ tends to can be solved using formula where you solve $e$ raised to the power of limit of $(f(x)-1)g(x)$ where $x$ tends to $∞$

Comment: Hey, I know I haven't shown process in detail, but I just wanted to leave it at explanation. If you want the whole process, let me know, but please don't downvote.